# Changing \closing indents in koma-script scrlttr2 class

Tags: indentation, koma-script, scrlttr2

The koma-script letter class scrlttr2 uses the DIN 5008 letter format by default.

I am happy to use the format, but it insists on indenting the `\closing` line, even if `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` is set.

How can I configure it so that it justifies *everything* in the letter body block-left? As far as I know, that is not incompatible with DIN 5008. I tried reading the koma-script guide, but everything I could find about changing block position referred to the "advanced user" section on pseudospacing. I am not an advanced user. I am not even a beginner, and in fact the DIN.lco file already sets the sigindent to 0 mm, so I have no idea why it insists on indenting this one line.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GaramondNo8}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\nonfrenchspacing

\setkomavar{fromname}{Ole Nordmann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Storebakken 15 \\ 5500 Haugesund}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+47 5222 8183}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Christine Lagarde \\ Director \\ International Monetary Fund
\\ 700 19th Street, N.W. \\ Washington, D.C. 20431 \\ United States of America}

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{Request for a loan}
\setkomavar{customer}{4455992}
\opening{Dear Ms. Lagarde,}

Attached please find my application for a home loan. Since the financial crisis, my family and I have been living in a tent. We're hopeful that in this fifth year, you'll see fit to grant us the credit we need to start our new life.\\

In 2009, my income for the year was almost zero.\\

In 2010, my mortgage was foreclosed on, the house seized by the bank, rented to Korean drug lords, turned into a marijuana grow operation, raided by police, then razed and the leftover wood thrown into a chipper. As a result, the rental income in 2010 for the basement suite was limited and went mostly to cover court costs.\\

I trust nonetheless that my prior years as a reliable debtor will give you sufficient confidence to accept this loan risk.

\closing{Sincerely}
\encl{loan application, gift certificate for chocolate}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

or not. As a new user, I can't post images. You can try running the code yourself, and you'll see what I mean.

Note the indentation of "Sincerely" -- that is what I am talking about. How can I make the whole thing left-justified? My next question will be how to adjust paragraph spacing so that I don't have to do `\\` , which seems very wrong to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You vertical skip between the paragraphs can be done by the option `parskip`. So load the class with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=full,]{scrlttr2}
```

The adjustment of `\closing` depends on the definition of `\raggedsignature` which is set to `\centering` so you can change it as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
```

Based on this modification the following example results:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=full,]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{GaramondNo8}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\nonfrenchspacing

\setkomavar{fromname}{Ole Nordmann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Storebakken 15 \\ 5500 Haugesund}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+47 5222 8183}
\makeatletter


\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Christine Lagarde \\ Director \\ International Monetary Fund
\\ 700 19th Street, N.W. \\ Washington, D.C. 20431 \\ United States of America}

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{Request for a loan}
\setkomavar{customer}{4455992}
\opening{Dear Ms. Lagarde,}

Attached please find my application for a home loan. Since the financial crisis, my family and I have been living in a tent. We're hopeful that in this fifth year, you'll see fit to grant us the credit we need to start our new life.

In 2009, my income for the year was almost zero.

In 2010, my mortgage was foreclosed on, the house seized by the bank, rented to Korean drug lords, turned into a marijuana grow operation, raided by police, then razed and the leftover wood thrown into a chipper. As a result, the rental income in 2010 for the basement suite was limited and went mostly to cover court costs.

I trust nonetheless that my prior years as a reliable debtor will give you sufficient confidence to accept this loan risk.

\closing{Sincerely}
\encl{loan application, gift certificate for chocolate}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I am going to go and read the documentation to find out how to determine the setting of existing commands like \raggedsignature...

Comment: @StephenBosch: I am a German and use the German version of the documentation which is more in detail. However there is an English version on berlios available which isn't proof read: http://www.komascript.de/scrguien-draft